# SQL Server Pivot Data on latest results

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, pivot, aggregate

I  have data in the format:

```
pkid, tablename, tablekeyid, attrname, attrvalue,createdate
```

Data in the table can be a repeat of `attrname` such as:

```
1, Foo, 1, attr1, value1, 2016-01-01 02:02:02
2, Foo, 1, attr1, value2, 2016-02-01 03:03:03
3, Foo, 2, attr2, value3, 2016-02-01 03:03:03
```

Now I want this information in following format with Pivot

```
tablekeyid   attr1    attr2
    1        value2   NULL
    2        NULL     value3
```

Basically, it should result in the latest values.

1. How this can be accomplished with aggregate function of Pivot?
2. Can this be filtered on the basis of tablename?
3. Does Entity Framework 5 (EF5) support pivot?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Works in Sql server),

```
SELECT tablekeyid,
       attr1,
       attr2
FROM   (SELECT tablekeyid,
               attr1,
               attr2,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER(
                   PARTITION BY tablekeyid
                   ORDER BY tablekeyid, createdate DESC) AS RN
        FROM   #Your_Pivot_Table
               PIVOT(Max(attrvalue)
                    FOR attrname IN([attr1],
                                    [attr2]) ) AS PivotSales)A
WHERE  A.RN = 1
```